# How To Access The Request Object in an MVC 6 Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Using Asp.Net 5 MVC 6 Controllers I am porting Api Controllers over and cant seem to work out how to access the request object inside the actions of a controller.

Example of Controller:

```
[Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization.Authorize(Roles = "Admin,User")]
    public class DataManagementController
    {
        [Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Prospects()
        {
           if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the abopve code Request in the if condition isnt found and VS resolve only offers a beta version of using Microsoft.Net.Http.Server

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inherit from `Controller`;

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,User")]
public class DataManagementController : Controller // inherit
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Prospects()
    {
        if (!HttpContext.Request.HasFormContentType)
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```